# Jquery unbind event listeners on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do i need to call the .unbind() jquery function in the DOM ready function before reattaching the .on listener or are the event listeners re-assigned on page refresh ?

Comment: yes they are....

Comment: so, the .unbind() does not need to happen everytime before attaching the .on() listener ?

Answer (score 1):

If you refresh you page, all your Javascript state is lost (variables, event bindings, but not local storage) and so there is no need to unbind things.

You will use `off` (or `unbind`) in the cases you don't need the event binding anymore (without refresh of the page). 
For example, jquery's `.one(”click", ..` on a button ensures the bound function on the button is only triggered once - clicking a second time on the button won't trigger the bound function. Inside Jquery it is doing an `.off` after first trigger to unbind the event binding. 
Note: "once" counts here also from a page refresh.

PS. [`unbind` is indeed deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/), it has been replaced with `off`  . But that  isn't important for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary, note that unbind is deprecated and you should use off instead.